# ProtectedLocalStorage.SetAsync() doesn't save nested properties?

Tags: c#, local-storage, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am working on a golf scorecard web app in Blazor (server side). I want it to do one of the following:

- On first render, it should load the scorecard (if any exist) from the local storage.
- On all following renders (changes) it should save the scorecard to the local storage, so that it is always updated with the newest values.

My code:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loading scorecard from local storage...");
        var result = await ProtectedLocalStorage.GetAsync<Scorecard>("scorecard");
        if (result.Success)
            scorecard = result.Value;

        StateHasChanged();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Saving scorecard to local storage...");
        if (scorecard != null)
            await ProtectedLocalStorage.SetAsync("scorecard", scorecard);
    }
}
```

I have checked that the `Get` and `Set` are reached as intended. I have also checked that on `Set`, the values of the scorecard are as they should be. But once I reach `Get` again, the score are reset to 0.

The `Scores` are a list of `HoleScore`'s on the `Scorecard` class, like this:

```
public class Scorecard
{
    (...)
    public List<HoleScore> Scores { get; } = new List<HoleScore>();
}

public record HoleScore
{
    public Guid PlayerId { get; set; }
    public int HoleNumber { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfStrokes { get; set; }
}
```

It is the value `NumberOfStrokes` that is reset to zero every time it loads (or maybe it's never saved). Why is that?

Comment: The semi-colon was a typo, it has been removed :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (de)seializer needs to be able to set properties.

```
//public List<HoleScore> Scores { get; } = new List<HoleScore>();
  public List<HoleScore> Scores { get; set; } = new List<HoleScore>();
```

or, as  has come up in the comments:

```
  public List<HoleScore> Scores { get; init; } = new List<HoleScore>();
```

to provide unintended access.

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable suggestion. I will try it once I am at the computer again. But if this is the case, the. Why aren’t there any errors or warnings?

Comment: The JSon serializer goes for flexibility, not validation.

Comment: Cool, it works. Thanks for the help. Bonus info: It also works with `init`.

Comment: Does the deserializer work with `internal set;`? I dislike public access “just for” serializers.

Comment: @user2864740: No, but you can replace `set;` with `init;` for more or less the same protection.

Comment: Ahh, `init;` looks so useful — so many things not C#7 :-/